# (Java)map class cannot recognize 2nd part text after split () the input text

Tags: java, dictionary, split, reduce

I am trying to get cited patents text with cite_95.txt file.
Here is my code for MapClass:

```
public static class MapClass
   extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

//private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

private Text cited = new Text();
private Text citing = new Text();
private IntWritable count  = new IntWritable(1);
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String[] itr = value.toString().split(",");
citing.set(itr[0]);
  cited.set(itr[1]);
context.write(cited,count);}}
```

when i ran the job, it thrown the error:

> Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>   why it cannot get the its[1] text?

thanks.

Edit:

Hi, this is my entire code sample:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class PatentCount1 {

public static class MapClass
   extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private Text cited = new Text();
private Text citing = new Text();
private IntWritable count  = new IntWritable(1);
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String[] itr = value.toString().split(",");

 cited.set(itr[1]);
 context.write(cited,count);
 }
 }
 public static class IntSumReducer
   extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
 private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
 @Override
 public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  for (IntWritable val: values) {
    sum += val.get();
  }
  result.set(sum);
  context.write(key, result);
 }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
job.setJarByClass(PatentCount1.class);
job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
 }
```

When I tried to get the 1st part text, it works:

```
 cited.set(itr[0]);
 context.write(cited,count);
```

Edit:

The input file is like:

- "CITING","CITED"
- 4658385,37596
- 3658699,3748596

Comment: If there is no comma in `value` then itr[1] is invalid.

Comment: Check itr.length before accessing any index in it.

Comment: @DavidChoweller There is comma in the value. In the file, citing and cited information  is listed per line, like this:  9847583, 234454. MapClass turned this line to be LongWritable, basically, it won't skip "," ,correct?

Comment: Did you check itr.length?

Comment: Please, provide more information about your code, preferably the call to `map()` method you're making.

Comment: It is in mapclass. Idon't know how to add code to check the length ? Could you simply provide me with a guide to check it.

Comment: Check the value of itr.length by printing it out.